# Marklogic Transactional property with server side JavaScript

Tags: transactions, marklogic, rollback, serverside-javascript, acid

I was trying to run a server side JavaScript code in marklogic to understand the transaction property of marklogic.
I have 2 statements, one update and another query statement in a single transaction.

Below is my JavaScript code :

```
declareUpdate({explicitCommit: true});

xdmp.documentInsert("/docs/first.json", {"first": 1});

fn.doc("/docs/first.json");

xdmp.commit();

//xdmp.rollback()
```

The above code running in a Query Console is supposed to insert "/docs/first.json" and then query "/docs/first.json".The first statement within the transaction which is document insert is working fine but then the second statement is not running and the query is returning me "null".
Also when I was using xdmp.rollback it threw an error:**[javascript] TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of null**. Can anyone please explain this because within a single transaction the statements should be able to see the results of the previously executed statements. 
The same query I had executed in Xquery and I was able to see a result.

Below is my Xquery code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare option xdmp:commit "explicit";

xdmp:document-insert('/docs/mst1.xml', <data/>);

fn:doc('/docs/mst1.xml');

xdmp:document-insert('/docs/mst2.xml', fn:doc('/docs/mst1.xml'));

xdmp:rollback()
```

The above code is returning me the result document present in uri '/docs/mst1.xml' which is `<data> </data>`

Answer (score 3):

Based on my understanding of [the documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_13597), it's not possible to execute multi-statement transactions this way from JavaScript:

> - In XQuery, semi-colon acts as a separator between statements in the same transaction.
> - In Server-Side JavaScript, the entire program (script) is considered a single transactional statement, regardless how many JavaScript statements it contains.

You may need to rely on functions like `xdmp.invokeFunction` to explicitly commit multiple statement transactions from JavaScript.